# With same keyboard shorcut, is it possible to make application one execute before global one?

Tags: 14.04, unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, compiz

I have many Compiz or Ubuntu keyboard shortcuts defined. I know some of them may override others applications ones. In case of conflict I'd like specific applications keyboard shortcuts to be executed instead - or before - global ones.
Is it possible? Is there some priority list stored or is it rather hardcoded?